# R plot axes tick labels

Tags: r

When I do a plot function in R i get 
marks on the axes, for examples:

```
set.seed(123)
plot(matrix(rnorm(100),50,2))
```

puts marks at (y axis) of {-2,-1,0,1,2}.

My question is:

How can I get these values returned as a vector? Something like:

```
> GetTickMarkValues()
[1] -2 -1  0  1  2
```

Comment: Do you mean how can you set their values? Their values are clearly -2,-1,0,1,2 and whatever the x-value of the y-axis is.

Comment: no: how can i get/save their values (in a variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives you the extreme values for tick marks and the number of intervals between them:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
plot(x,y)  
par("xaxp")
[1] 1 5 4
```